# Página de destino do Formulário via GET com link personalizado

Tags: php

Possuo um formulário que envia dados via `GET`, encaminhando os dados para a pagina `busca2.php`, conforme mostrado abaixo:

```
<form action = "busca2.php" method = "GET" id="formulario">
```

Ao submeter o formulario, o link fica da seguinte forma:

```
busca2.php?campo1=x&campo2=y&campo3=z(e etc)
```

Estou querendo passar este link para url amigável. Já sei implementar os comandos dentro do arquivo `htaccess`. Minha dúvida consiste em submeter o formluário diretamente para a url já personalizada, para tipo:

```
busca/14/16/17/18(e etc)
```

Como devo proceder?

De toda forma, obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, eu imagino uma função em javascript para resolver isso.

```
<script>
function enviaDados(){

    var campos = [
        document.getElementById('campo1').value,
        document.getElementById('campo2').value,
        document.getElementById('campo3').value
    ]

    campos = campos.join('/');

    window.location='/busca/' + campos;

    return false;
}
</script>


<form action="" method="GET" id="formulario" onsubmit="return enviaDados();">
    <input type="text" id="campo1" value="11" />
    <input type="text" id="campo2" value="2222" />
    <input type="text" id="campo3" value="33333" />
    <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
</form>
```

Comment: Olá, Givanildo. Vou fazer o teste e logo retorno com o resultado obtido. Obrigado.

Comment: Ok Givanildo , deu certinho. obrigado.